# Automatically start (Apache, mysql and FTP) on Xampp startup (OSX)

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, ftp, xampp

Is it possible to automatically start the 3 XAMPP Control modules (Apache, mysql and FTP) when starting the app on Mac OSX? 
The thing is, everyday when I boot Xampp I have to click "Start", "Start" and "Start" (and insert system password) to activate the 3 modules. This is not a life or death topic, but I'm pretty sure it is useful for a lot of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and configure Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) or just use MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). Just not sure if MAMP has FTP.

Comment: Yup! Thanks for the tips bro! I've always been a little bit reluctant about MAMP but today i've installed it again today to check out the new features and looks really better compared to the last time I saw it (a couple years ago). ;)
Homebrew looks great but it doesn't fit my needs right now. 
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

That's possible on any system,

I'm not using mac but you should always find instructions for that into your server start page

run your server then go to the `HOW-TO Guides` section

you'll find `Auto-Start XAMPP` {[localhost/dashboard/docs/auto-start-xampp.html](http://localhost/dashboard/docs/auto-start-xampp.html)}

if you have a problem you could look at `Troubleshoot Apache Startup Problems` {[localhost/dashboard/docs/troubleshoot-apache.html](http://server.local/dashboard/docs/troubleshoot-apache.html)}